# Search for particular string in file and replace the value

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and was scratching my head for something that seems pretty trivial. I was trying to search for particular string in file and replace that value with the new value . Here is what I have:

```
file = open('file.txt') { |f| f.grep(/release/) }
```

The contents of the file `file.txt` is as follows:

```
develop: 0.0.0
release: 0.0.4
test: 0.0.0
```

I am getting the output of the above line in array as follows :

> ["release: 0.0.4\n"]

How do I change just the value of this line in above file to the new version, something like this :

```
develop: 0.0.0
release: 0.0.5
test: 0.0.0
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "replace ... to the new version"? Do you want to store that result to a variable? (Do you want that variable to be a  string, or an array of 3 strings?) Or do you want to save it to a new file? Or do you want to update the original file?

Comment: In the case of the latter two options, is it actually a requirement that you do this in ruby, or could you just do it on the command line, e.g. with `sed`? And does this question actually have anything to do with `ruby-on-rails`? If not, there's no need to tag it as such.

Comment: Ya I guess it has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails, sorry for the wrong tag. And regarding replacing, I was basically looking to replace the value of release in that specific file . So basically updating the existing file and won’t be new file .

Comment: If this is a YAML file why not read the data, manipulate it, and dump it back out? That avoids mangling things by accident, like a `prev_release` line you may not realize could show up.

Comment: I was trying to  add this part of script of changing the release version as part of my existing ruby script ( Rakefile )

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks @tadman for the suggestion. I used Yaml to load and manipulate the file. It worked great .

Comment: If you've got some working code it's worth posting a self-answer.

Comment: If it's a YAML file, then you should probably store it as `file.yml`, not `file.txt` :)

Comment: @TomLord yeah basically I did not have any extension for the file till now, would probably save it as yml now.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the assistance ! Appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on above suggestions from @tadman, I was able to get it working as follows:

```
require 'yaml'

file = YAML.load_file('file')
file["release"] = "#{new_version}"
file.open('file', 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(file, f) }
```